# Trying to get only numbers when update from access database to textbox in C#

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, c#-4.0, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I just started using C# and I a have a textbox on a form. I want to display only numbers from ACCESS database, Like string stored in database is 12Kg but when I do update i should return only value i.e.12, I have searched but not getting any idea, I hope you can help me...

---

Query:

```cs
"Update Para Set PartNumber = '"+ txtPartNoL.Text + "', MacID = '" + cmb.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'"+" Para1 = '" + txtPara1L.Text + "', PType1 = '" + lblLPara1.Text + "'," + " val(LabourPara.Para4) = '" + txtPara4L.Text + "', PType4 = '" + lblLPara4.Text + "'," + " Qty = '" + txtQtyL.Text + "', PF = '" + txtPFL.Text + "', SF = '" + txtSFL.Text + "'," + " Amount = '" + txtAmt.Text + "'" + " WHERE QoNumber = '" + txtNo.Text + "' AND PartNumber = '" + txtPartNo.Text + "'";
```

Comment: This is confusing. Why use UPDATE? If database stores `12Kg`, do you want to change the record? Why would db have `12Kg` instead of just `12` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You are updating everything as text, which can't be true for at least quantity and amount, so try:

```cs
sql = "Update Para Set PartNumber = '"+ txtPartNoL.Text + "', MacID = '" + cmb.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' " + 
"Para1 = '" + txtPara1L.Text + "', PType1 = '" + lblLPara1.Text + "', " + 
"LabourPara.Para4 = " + Val(txtPara4L.Text) + ", PType4 = '" + lblLPara4.Text + "', " + 
"Qty = " + txtQtyL.Text + ", PF = '" + txtPFL.Text + "', SF = '" + txtSFL.Text + "', " + 
"Amount = " + txtAmt.Text + " " + 
"WHERE QoNumber = " + txtNo.Text + " AND PartNumber = '" + txtPartNo.Text + "'";
```

However, avoid this concatenating mess and - *asap* - go and learn how to use *parameters*.

Comment: This is not mess. According to my Project its CORRECT. There is no error in this query . what i want is, Like we can write "VAL(abc123)" in SELECT QUERY to get only numbers(i.e. 123), but how to write this in UPDATE query, Like when i press update button. In TextBox it Should Return only Number.

Comment: Yes, that's how I modified it. But `Val("abc123")` will return 0 (zero).